# How do I setup Java OpenID Server (JOIDS)?

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, openid

I'm stuck on this step:

```
Then you should modify the file
in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/,
especially the database and mail configurations, and the password for
domain configurator(the name of the environment variable is
"domain.configurator.password").
```

That file doesn't seem to exist.  I've got the database (PostGreSQL) and Tomcat both up, running, and generally configured.  I can hit the JOIDS management page, but can't login as I can't find the config file referenced that I'm supposed to set the password in...  Google only returns a couple hits on this project, one of which was very helpful in setting up the database, but doesn't explain how to resolve my config problem.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Tomcat 7, you need to enable automatic creation of this file in `server.xml`.